# Rails single-table-inheritance vs. old data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance

I have a STI setup in Rails (names have been changed to protect the innocent)

`class Mercedes < Car`

`class BMW < Car`

Now at some stage I need to remove references to `Mercedes` from the code, but want to leave the data in place for historical reasons.

When I try to load all records from the `cars` table, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed
to locate the subclass: 'Mercedes'. This error is raised because the column 'type'
is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this
column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class
or overwrite Car.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
```

Is there a way to ignore records in the `cars` table whose `type` is `Mercedes`?

Comment: what is the query you tried to execute

Comment: @GhostRider I was trying to execute BMW.all when it blew up. So the leftover data renders the whole table useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `default_scope { where("cars.type != 'Mercedes'") }` to your `Car` class.

HOWEVER: I would not advise leaving this old data in your production database if it's going to cause to you build in workarounds like this. If you need to keep it, make an archive, and then remove it from the db, or restructure the data so it works with whatever code changes you need to make.

Comment: @mu: I'm still stuck in Rails 3 land.

Comment: Ah I see. Good point. I've edited the question to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: I still think "don't do it" is the best part of your answer :)

Comment: That was the recommendation of a colleague too. I was wondering why the framework itself doesn't provide this, looks like Rails already took care of it! Great answer; thanks! (and the "don't do it" answer is what we actually went with, so that's a good'un as well :) )